# C++ assigning pointer to another pointer locally in a function - undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, pointers

My question is related to assigning pointers to another pointer. In the code below in the method `next_schedulable_operation()`. The member variable `candidates_` has elements of type `mlir::Operation*`. I have an iterator `op_itr` to one of the elements in `candidates_`. Prior to erasing the elements from `candidates_` I make a local copy of the pointer(?) with the line of code `mlir::Operation* op = *op_itr;`

Then on last line, I assign the local variable to the member variable `schedulable_op_` with the line `schedulable_op_ = op`;

Will this result in undefined behaviour? I cannot work with the object `mlir::Operation` as it says that the destructor is private.

```
error: ‘mlir::Operation::~Operation()’ is private within this context
```

Code

Comment: unless dereference or delete, pointers are just numbers.  Something like, you copied an address card of a building, and destroy the original one, the copyied one is still valid as long as the building is still there.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not undefined behavior.

The initialization of `op` will copy the pointer value out of the list. The subsequent `erase` call will delete the list node. This will call the destructor for a `mlir::Operation *` which will do nothing because it is a raw pointer. Whatever that node's pointer is pointing to will still be there.